# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug' Gradle

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

This is my gradle build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.peep"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.1"
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.11.0'
    compile 'com.javon.parserecyclerviewadapter:parserecyclerviewadapter:1.0.4'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your default config add this: `multidexEnabled true` and then add this dependency to your project `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0`

For more information please refer to this link http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/tools/building/multidex.html#mdex-gradle

Comment: Yes I did follow the instructions now I am getting Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/parse/ConnectivityNotifier$ConnectivityListener.class

Comment: So you probably have two classes with the same name within your project. If you have written a class called ConnectivityListener try to rename and see what happens. I would recommend you to clean/rebuild your project

Comment: Typo `multiDexEnabled true`